Webapp requiring service account re-authentication
We're working on a node.js web app hosted on a compute engine. Data is in firestore. Files in buckets on GCP as well. The service account with all the necessary permissions is also on the compute engine owner. The key is in secret manager.
Everything works fine but we're required to rerun "gcloud auth login serviceAcct" every few hours. If we don't the app stops working, sometimes the page renders but can't access firestore.
Our firestoreconfig:
const { SecretManagerServiceClient } = require('@google-cloud/secret-manager');
const { Firestore } = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const { SecretManagerServiceClient } = require('@google-cloud/secret-manager');
const secretManagerClient = new SecretManagerServiceClient();
const secretName = 'projects/projectnameHere/secrets/secretNameHere/versions/latest';

async function GetFirebaseAccessManager() {
try {
const [secretVersion] = await secretManagerClient.accessSecretVersion({ name: secretName });
const serviceAccountKey = JSON.parse(secretVersion.payload.data.toString());
//
return { firestore: GeneratefirebaseObject(serviceAccountKey), storage: GeneratestorageObject(serviceAccountKey) }
} catch (error) {
console.error('Error accessing secret version:', error);
}
}

function GeneratefirebaseObject(serviceAccountKey){
const firestore = new Firestore({
projectId: serviceAccountKey.project_id,
databaseId: 'dbName-firestore',
credentials: {client_email: serviceAccountKey.client_email,private_key:serviceAccountKey.private_key}
});
return firestore;
}

unction GeneratestorageObject(serviceAccountKey){
    const storage = new Storage({
        projectId: serviceAccountKey.project_id,
        credentials: {client_email: serviceAccountKey.client_email,private_key:serviceAccountKey.private_key}
    });
    return storage

}


module.exports = {
    firebaseObjects: GetFirebaseAccessManager(),
};

Any idea what to look for?
We also tried setting GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS and point it to a local copy of the key json file, updated the firestoreconfig. That did not work.
Setting the service account key explicitly in the code works but this is not recommended so we need another solution. Any ideas?

Your approach is incorrect. When you're running on a Google compute service (Compute Engine, Cloud Run, GKE etc. etc.) you should use the identity attached to the resource (in this case the Compute Engine VM). Then, Application Default Credentials will automatically acquire the credentials for you (there's also no need to generate a key) and token renewal will occur every 3600s. See attached Service Account

So drop the code above and do something like:
`const { Firestore } = require('@g...');
const { Storage } = require('@g...');
async function GetFirebaseAccessManager() {
try {
const firestore = new Firestore();
const storage = new Storage();
    return { firestore, storage };
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Error initializing Firebase services:', error);
    throw error; 
}

}
module.exports = {
firebaseObjects: GetFirebaseAccessManager(),
};`

Correct. Preferably, when you create the VM(s), you bind them to a user-defined Service Account but, for testing, you could temporarily add the IAM roles to the default Compute Engine Service Account. The clients will acquire the credentials automatically from the Metadata Service.

Thanks. The VM is already bound to a service account. Following the link I did
gcloud auth application-default login instead of specifying service account by name.
I also added the key json to the VM and specified GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in the pm2 env then restarted. I did not change the original code and I have not been prompted again since. Perhaps the original code is now doing more than it needs to. Thanks!

I'm pleased to hear it's working. When you use the Service Account bound to a resource (e.g. the VM), you should not use GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS (please see my previous link) and gcloud auth is a completely separate (unrelated|irrelevant) process.
